Strange MIME type (application/x-dbf) for a P7M
I'm working in analyzing a bunch of P7M files using Python and when parsing them i get into some with strange MIME type = application/x-dbf. I saw that this mime type is used for some vectoring and db so, if anyone knows and wants to explain me why is placed this strange MIME type inside it will be so useful (in addition who modifies and manipulates in the pipeline of extracting this kind of files is also useful to know).
If helps: the p7m is a signed protocol to digital sign some files (like pdf).
Thanks in advance to anyone wants to help me to understand!
I'm expecting the MIME type application/pkcs7-mime or application/x-pkcs7-mime.
